# JGroups with TCPPING (static peer list)

Tags: java, jgroups

I want to have a few instances of my Java app collaborating with one another. I tried using JGroups for that, with no success. I'm not using JBoss, just plain JGroups library 4.0.3.

I tried to make a 'minimal working example' with two instances which connect to one another. I tested as described in a single machine.

Once I ran two instances of my app what I expected was that they would print both their own and each other's addresses. What I got was that they just printed they own addresses. It seems they have not managed to connect to one another.

Here comes my Java code:

```
import org.jgroups.Address;
import org.jgroups.JChannel;
import org.jgroups.View;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JChannel ch = new JChannel("./test.xml");
        ch.connect("TestCluster");

        final int SLEEP_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 1000;
        while (true) {
            checkNeighbors(ch);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME_IN_MILLIS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Ignored
            }
        }
    }

    private static void checkNeighbors(JChannel channel) {
        View view = channel.getView();
        List<Address> addresses = view.getMembers();
        System.out.println("NEIGHBORS:");
        for (Address address : addresses) {
            System.out.println("    " + address);
        }
    }
}
```

Here comes 'test.xml' for the first process:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups.xsd">
    <TCP bind_port="7950"
         recv_buf_size="${tcp.recv_buf_size:130k}"
         send_buf_size="${tcp.send_buf_size:130k}"
         max_bundle_size="64K"
         sock_conn_timeout="300"

         thread_pool.min_threads="0"
         thread_pool.max_threads="20"
         thread_pool.keep_alive_time="30000"/>

    <TCPPING async_discovery="true"
             initial_hosts="${jgroups.tcpping.initial_hosts:localhost[7900],localhost[7950]}"
             port_range="2"/>
    <MERGE3  min_interval="10000"
             max_interval="30000"/>
    <FD_SOCK/>
    <FD timeout="3000" max_tries="3" />
    <VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="1500"  />
    <BARRIER />
    <pbcast.NAKACK2 use_mcast_xmit="false"
                   discard_delivered_msgs="true"/>
    <UNICAST3 />
    <pbcast.STABLE desired_avg_gossip="50000"
                   max_bytes="4M"/>
    <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true" join_timeout="2000"
                view_bundling="true"/>
    <MFC max_credits="2M"
         min_threshold="0.4"/>
    <FRAG2 frag_size="60K"  />
    <!--RSVP resend_interval="2000" timeout="10000"/-->
    <pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER/>
</config>
```

For the second process I just changed the bind port to 7900.

My output was just each process printing its own address, like follows:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
GMS: address=CAPYBARA-PC-5951, cluster=TestCluster, physical address=fd5c:92d6:98b5:0:c5ee:90c9:e7b0:ceb2:7950
-------------------------------------------------------------------
NEIGHBORS:
    CAPYBARA-PC-5951
NEIGHBORS:
    CAPYBARA-PC-5951
NEIGHBORS:
    CAPYBARA-PC-5951
NEIGHBORS:
    CAPYBARA-PC-5951
NEIGHBORS:
    CAPYBARA-PC-5951
```

Every time I run 5951 changes to a different number.

Does anyone have a clue what I did wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to define `bind_addr` in `TCP` and list all hosts in `TCPPING`, e.g. if you have 2 processes running on `192.168.1.5::7950` and `192.168.1.6::7900`, then the config for the first member needs to include:

```
<TCP bind_addr="192.168.1.5" bind_port="7950">
<TCPPING initial_hosts="192.168.1.5[7950],192.168.1.6[7900]"/>
```

and the config for the second members should include:

```
<TCP bind_addr="192.168.1.6" bind_port="7900">
<TCPPING initial_hosts="192.168.1.5[7950],192.168.1.6[7900]"/>
```

As you can see, `TCPPING` lists all members' bind addresses and their ports.

You could use the *same* configuration by using system properties, e.g.

```
<TCP bind_addr="${my.bind_addr:192.168.1.6}" bind_port="${my.bind_port:7900}"> and start a process with `-Dmy.bind_addr=1.2.3.4` and `-Dmy.bind_port=12345`.
```

Also check the JGroups manual for symbolic names for bind addresses, e.g. `localhost`, `site_local` or `match-address:xxx`.

Comment: Perhaps also try using IPv4: `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Comment: It worked! I put my hostname (CAPYBARA-PC) both in bind_addr and in initial_hosts.

    <TCP bind_addr="CAPYBARA-PC"
         bind_port="7900"
         recv_buf_size="${tcp.recv_buf_size:130k}"
         send_buf_size="${tcp.send_buf_size:130k}"
         max_bundle_size="64K"
         sock_conn_timeout="300"
         thread_pool.min_threads="0"
         thread_pool.max_threads="20"
         thread_pool.keep_alive_time="30000"/>
    <TCPPING async_discovery="true"
             initial_hosts="CAPYBARA-PC[7900],CAPYBARA-PC[7950]"
             port_range="2"/>